# real time use case of treemap and hashmap?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, treemap

In real time project, when we go for `HashMap` and `TreeMap`?

In what condition, we choose both?

There are also different data structure in Java `Collection`, so, what's the reason to use `TreeMap` or `HashMap`? and any short example?

Comment: Hint: do some prior research the next time.

Comment: [Java Collection matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JSBPho-Df_1Km0SxXfjW8a8PRLLTeoDDiY8ePs_Ac-c/pub)

Comment: Real time, or real life? Real time has a specific meaning, and I don't think it is what you mean.

Comment: Treemap has been widely applied to various financial applications and one of the most famous is the SmartMoney which uses treemap to display information.